# Why there are so many methods of getting date time in java?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have been working on a simple dictionary based android application so i thought to search for best practices to be used in the development. So i searched for the best methods for getting time and date but i found so many methods all resulting into date and time.

For example: [Java - How to get current time and date](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

Here i found multiple methods to get the time and date with formatting as well.

**Code Snippets**

For java.util.Date, just create a new Date()

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For java.util.Calendar, uses Calendar.getInstance()

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For java.time.LocalDateTime, uses LocalDateTime.now()

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(now)); //2016/11/16 12:08:43
```

For java.time.LocalDate, uses LocalDate.now()

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(dtf.format(localDate)); //2016/11/16
```

Why there are so many methods of getting date time in java?And Also what's the best method of getting the date and time?

Comment: "Grown historically". In the past, Java date/time routines had pretty bad design. Many people preferred libraries like JodaTime. Finally in Java 8 date/time packages were updated (it's essentially JodaTime).
Nowadays I prefer Java 8 `java.time.*` package (the last two options from what you list).
Also note that `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` are not "different methods". These are "different things" - date and date-time. So these are not alternatives.

Comment: I guess it has to do that Java is world-wide known and used, and as libraries are built every day, it was a matter of time before one's life became easier and could use dates with a lot of ways, according to what country one lives. I don't think there is an answer to your question based on facts, let alone that date and date&time are different and one replacing the other is wrong.

Comment: @lexicore, thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because date and time are complicated things like how to deal with currency and how to convert text to bytes and back.

You *should* be using the `java.time` package introduced in Java 8, as they've fixed things and tried to make it less annoying and weird. It was based on [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which is a well thought out library.

`Date` and `Calendar` are parts of the old time/date API, although there wasn't that much of an API, the classes were stuck to `java.util` and there were lots of design issues. They still work, but you shouldn't really use them in new code. Not because they're deprecated (they're not), but because they're bad. Imagine `Date` is to `Instant` like `Vector` is to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Java 8 time is not available on all android versions. Afaik google recommends to use Calendar

Comment: I see the pros and cons, but for older Android devices IMHO the best you can do is add [TheeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use the functionality of java.time. If that disagrees with a Google recommendation, then I disagree with the Google recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Date can give you the date and time, but you can't do much else with it. Calendar makes it possible to manipulate the date and time with things like skipping to next Wednesday, or adding a month (which is a number of days depending on the current month). As others have said, LocalDate(Time) is only available from API level 26 but has specific methods for manipulating the date (and time) instead of Calendar's function(field name, amount) style.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Calendar.

Date is Deprecated or not suggest.

LocalDate and LocalDateTime required API 26.